# Can jupyter notebook autocomplete so intelligently like pycharm?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I think jupyter's autocomplete by `tab` is very limited.I know we can use jupyter notebook in pycharm,but it works not very well for me.I try to seek this functionality like pycharm or ST3 package `anaconda` .

Actually,I expecte the functionality like this kind when you import some module and write `modules.`,it will remind you what attributes you can use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is precisely the result you're looking for, but you could try running this in a Notebook cell:

`%config IPCompleter.greedy=True`

Then hit the `Tab` key when you want to autocomplete. I'm not sure if it brings anything newer than what you already see.

Answer (score 1):

I just found an extension called `Hinterland` which satisfied my need.You just install python package `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` and you will find some other useful extensions.

Comment: I've used Hinterland for the past days and I find it very uncomfortable, it makes weird suggestions, it suggests when it shouldn't suggest and it writes it suggestions into my code when it shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can, but with awesome extension. Inspired by [TabNine](https://tabnine.com/blog/), I developed an extension for Jupyter Notebook, 
[github repo](https://github.com/wenmin-wu/jupyter-tabnine).

This extension is now available on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-tabnine/). Simply issue following **four** lines command and enjoy it:)

```
pip3 install jupyter-tabnine
jupyter nbextension install --py jupyter_tabnine
jupyter nbextension enable --py jupyter_tabnine
jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_tabnine
```

[image: demo]